# Is CloudKit data editable by user?

Tags: ios, cloudkit

I want to keep "restorable" data in cloud with CloudKit so that user is able to restore purchases after re-downloading the application. The question is, will user be able do access and edit this data from his iCloud dashboard or in any other way?

Answer (score 0):

No, only a developer will have access to the CloudKit dashboard. You have to add an editing feature in your app or create a website that uses the CloudKit JS API to make the changes.